# is the following series uniformly converges

Tags: analysis

My question is to determine whether the following are uniformly convergent or not:
sum of $\frac1{(nx)^2}$ for x in (0,1].

My attempt was to claim that of course it first converges pointwise. Fix an $x$, we can factor it outside and the sum converges pointwise to $\frac{\pi}{6x^2}$ , but this poinwise limit is unbounded as we go closer to 0? Is it a legitimate argument or perhaps I need to choose some $x$ such as $x=\frac1n$.

Comment: Got something from the answer?

Answer (score 2):

For every $n$, the rest $R_n(x)=\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k\geqslant n}\frac1{(kx)^2}$ is such that $$R_n(x)=\frac1{x^2}\sum\limits_{k\geqslant n}\frac1{k^2}\geqslant\frac1{x^2}\sum\limits_{k\geqslant n}\frac1{k(k+1)}=\frac1{x^2}\sum\limits_{k\geqslant n}\left(\frac1k-\frac1{k+1}\right)=\frac1{nx^2},$$ hence the function $R_n$ is unbounded on $(0,1]$. This forbids the uniform convergence of the series on $(0,1]$ (but a slight modification of the argument shows that the series converges uniformly on the interval $[\varepsilon,+\infty)$, for every positive $\varepsilon$).

The argument showing that the convergence is not uniform applies to every series $\sum\limits_{n}a_nu(x)$ such that $a_n\ne0$ for infinitely many $n$ and the function $u$ is unbounded.